# Erroneous traceroutes from certain GCP regions

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Can anyone explain why I receive seemingly erroneous traceroute results from some GCP regions?

I am running network analysis from Google Cloud Compute instances in various regions to our own data centres to verify our customer experience.

Here is a test site to show the issue:

```
$ ping www.bbc.co.uk
PING www.bbc.net.uk (212.58.249.210) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

I get the following traceroute from asia-east1-b:

```
asia-east1-b:~$ traceroute 212.58.249.210
traceroute to 212.58.249.210 (212.58.249.210), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  108.170.227.202 (108.170.227.202)  152.419 ms 209.85.255.194 (209.85.255.194)  155.181 ms 72.14.239.154 (72.14.239.154)  157.535 ms
 2  216.239.58.130 (216.239.58.130)  248.054 ms 72.14.232.71 (72.14.232.71)  160.910 ms 209.85.247.4 (209.85.247.4)  164.240 ms
 3  216.239.57.197 (216.239.57.197)  181.224 ms 216.239.58.255 (216.239.58.255)  176.807 ms 216.239.57.197 (216.239.57.197)  180.841 ms
 4  172.253.65.165 (172.253.65.165)  252.485 ms  252.262 ms *
 5  216.239.57.236 (216.239.57.236)  247.640 ms 209.85.250.90 (209.85.250.90)  243.427 ms 216.239.57.236 (216.239.57.236)  247.579 ms
 6  74.125.242.112 (74.125.242.112)  249.928 ms  247.138 ms  244.123 ms
```

However, from europe-west2-b I get no route:

```
europe-west2-b:~$ traceroute 212.58.249.210
traceroute to 212.58.249.210 (212.58.249.210), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
```

I can use curl and retrieve content successfully, so the route is valid and working.

I see this same issue with various hosts and about half of the GCP regions, seemingly at random around the world.

Including map of where we have unknown routes (red).

[image]

Comment: This is normal. Routers are not required to respond to ICMP messages. For paths inside private networks, this is not unusual.

Comment: Thank for the reply @JohnHanley. Are you suggesting the whole route goes inside Google's network until it reaches the BBC? This does not seem to correlate to distance (i.e. Asia vs Europe).

Comment: It depends on your GCP network service tier. For Premium, traffic enters at a location closest to the customer and stays on Google's backbone. For Standard, there are no guarantees on providers/paths, etc. Standard traffic typically enters Google's network at the region closest to the service, which means the public Internet for most of the route. However, that is not related to the fact, routers are not required to respond to ICMP (ping) message. Using ping and tracert to determine network delays is not reliable. They are designed to detect broken routes and not performance.

Comment: Included a map to better illustrate the issue @JohnHanley. What you've said doesn't seem to reconcile with the scale and distribution of the problem.

Comment: @Paul .. Hi Paul. How did you execute traceroute from GCP. We are unable to run traceroute and get the output. Could you pls suggest

Comment: @Arya I never managed to resolve this issue. As TheRovinRogue answered below, it seems this is by design.

Answer (score 1):

To reiterate some of what @JohnHanley has stated and to provide some additional context: GCP increases the TTL counter of packets leaving Compute Engine instances for the internet. This means [traceroute](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#traceroute) results (depending on where the source of trace was initiated) may show incomplete or missing expected output.